# How to enter unicode operators from keyboard in Scala IDE?

Tags: scala, operators, scala-ide

How to enter unicode operators from keyboard in Scala IDE? Operators like ⇒ and other two: <- and ->.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Scala -> Formatter -> Miscellaneous`, then tick "Rewrite arrow tokens"

You can then type => and it will be converted to ⇒ when you do an auto-format (Ctrl-Shift-F), and similarly for <- to ←

It doesn't seem to convert -> for some reason, though.

You may get problems (on Windows, at least) with the character encoding of the file - you may need to change this to UTF8 via the file's Properties dialog.

Comment: It is also possible to enable automatic formatting on save at Java -> Editor -> Save actions. Works for .scala files but doesn't work for scala sheets.